# How how use IF condition for comparing date with SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a MS ACCESS table from an attendance machine, which consists of USERID, CHECKTIME column.

With below SQL Query in MS Access, I manage to sort and find the MIN (date and time) as starting/clock in and MAX(date and time) as clock out per Day (date/Work_date)

```
SELECT MIN(a.CHECKTIME) as work_start_time,  MAX(a.CHECKTIME)   as work_end_time,  b.CheckDate as work_date, WEEKDAY(b.CheckDate,2) as work_day, a.USERID  as user_id 

FROM CHECKINOUT a RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT
  DateValue(CHECKTIME) as CheckDate,
  USERID FROM CHECKINOUT
  WHERE ( MONTH(CHECKTIME) = 4  )
  AND YEAR(CHECKTIME) = 2019 AND USERID =50
)      

b on a.USERID = b.USERID
and DateValue(a.CHECKTIME) = b.CheckDate GROUP BY b.checkDate, a.USERID
```

The result of query:

```
Work_start_Time        | work_end_time        | Work_date | Work_day |User_ID
1/04/2019 8:30:19 AM   | 1/04/2019 8:30:19 AM |  1/04/2019| 1        |50
2/04/2019 12:16:38 AM  | 2/04/2019 9:40:52 AM |  2/04/2019| 2        |50
3/04/2019 1:25:29 AM   | 3/04/2019 1:25:29 AM |  3/04/2019| 3        |50
4/04/2019 7:09:26 AM   | 4/04/2019 9:10:37 PM |  4/04/2019| 4        |50
```

What I wish to do is, if next day (CHECKTIME +1) work_start_time is less than 5AM then MIN(CHECKTIME) of next day becomes the Work_end_time.

```
SELECT MIN(a.CHECKTIME) as work_start_time,  

IF (MIN(a.CHECKTIME+1) < 5:00:00 AM )
 MIN(a.CHECKTIME+1) as work_end_time,
ELSE
 MAX(a.CHECKTIME)   as work_end_time, 

 b.CheckDate as work_date, WEEKDAY(b.CheckDate,2) as work_day, a.USERID  as user_id 

FROM CHECKINOUT a RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT
  DateValue(CHECKTIME) as CheckDate,
  USERID FROM CHECKINOUT
  WHERE ( MONTH(CHECKTIME) = 4  )
  AND YEAR(CHECKTIME) = 2019 AND USERID =50
)        

b on a.USERID = b.USERID
and DateValue(a.CHECKTIME) = b.CheckDate GROUP BY b.checkDate, a.USERID
```

The result of query:

```
Work_start_Time        | work_end_time        | Work_date | Work_day |User_ID
1/04/2019 8:30:19 AM   | 2/04/2019 12:16:38AM |  1/04/2019| 1        |50
2/04/2019 9:40:52 AM   | 3/04/2019 1:25:29 AM |  2/04/2019| 2        |50
3/04/2019 1:25:29 AM   | 3/04/2019 1:25:29 AM |  3/04/2019| 3        |50
4/04/2019 7:09:26 AM   | 4/04/2019 9:10:37 PM |  4/04/2019| 4        |50
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using *IIF*:

```
IIF(TimeValue(MIN(a.CHECKTIME)) < #05:00:00#), MIN(a.CHECKTIME+1), MAX(a.CHECKTIME)) as work_end_time,
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav,  the IIF statement is working but always false. i assuming < #05:00:00#   always give an false result

Comment: Yes. The date part must be excluded. See edited answer, please.

Comment: thank you Gustav, somehow still didn't give my expected logic. but it give me a point where to start and play around. many many Thanks.  awesome

Comment: You could provide some sample data. But if you feel so, please mark as answered.